hyphenation with single syllable words
I have narrow columns and \Large text ... even with an added
\hyphenation command and especially with single syllable words,
text goes outside the margins ... are there (yes?!) tweaks to get
the text all lines up?

Please show an example.

note unless you are using luatex the first word of each paragraph is not hyphenated unless you put \hspace*{0pt] at the start

\sloppy  or \raggedright is SOP for narrow columns.  See also \fussy.

Don't know how to paste an image here  ...

more important than an image is a small example that we can run

\emergencystretch seemed to fix the issue
